# how to use tamil font in android

Tags: android, fonts

this is my tamil UTF-8 unicode string

"\u00e0\u00ae\u009c\u00e0\u00af\u0086\u00e0\u00ae\u00a9\u00e0\u00ae\u00bf\u00e0\u00ae\u00b2\u00e0\u00ae\u00bf\u00e0\u00ae\u00af\u00e0\u00ae\u00be \u00e0\u00ae\u00aa\u00e0\u00af\u0081\u00e0\u00ae\u0095\u00e0\u00af\u0088\u00e0\u00ae\u00aa\u00e0\u00af\u008d\u00e0\u00ae\u00aa\u00e0\u00ae\u009f\u00e0\u00ae\u00ae\u00e0\u00af\u008d"

i want to decode it and display the tamil font

in android is this posible,how to do ?

please help me

Comment: are you using webview or textview

Comment: Go to other questions now, and accept the top-most answer, to provide expected feedback to the SO community.

Answer (score 9):

You can save the tamil (ttf) font in the assets folder, and use it like this:

```
TextView text; // initialize to your textview
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/tamil.ttf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** Download a tamil font `.ttf` file. (For example say **kanchi.ttf**).

**Step 2:** Now create a directory "**fonts**"  in your `assets` folder in the android project.

**Step 3:** Now copy the **kanchi.ttf** file into `assets/fonts` folder in you Android project.

**Step 4:** Add these lines to your `onCreate()`

```
protected static Typeface tamil = null;
tamil= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kanchi.ttf");
```

**Step 5:** Now provide this typeface to your `TextView` you want.

```
    textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipstext);
    textview.setTypeface(tamil);
    textview.setTextSize(20);
    textview.setText( "nkZk;");
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur help.i have another one doubt here i want to display like "இந்த மொழியில்: English" how to set this string in textview

Answer (score 3):

The best way to display tamil in android is to use TSCII font as described [here](http://lkalarani.blogspot.com/2011/04/tamil-in-android.html). Unicode is not yet fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webview, place the your font file 'tamilfont.ttf' in the assets folder. 
and the java code will be similar to this. notice the font is applied in the css

```
    data = "<html><head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'tamilfont';src: url('file:///android_asset/tamilfont.ttf');} h1 { font-family: 'tamilfont'; } </style></head><body> <h1>தமிழன்!</h1> </body></html>"; 
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

this approach does not work in android 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: hi i am using json and stored as string

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani: could you kindly point me where 'he' has mentioned webview. i presume that 'he' is 'me'. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I Have one to open Tamil font convert doc to pdf and then try to open in android phones

Comment: This is not the proper way to answer give some reference,code,links.