# Unicode issue in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a rss feed app that contains the title and the description in tamil language. When I display the title in a textview and the description in a webview it is displaying box characters. Kindly help me how to resolve this issue.
Below are the code

```
title.setText(data.title); //textview data.title has the tamil language text
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data.description, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to include a Tamil font with your application. Find an appropriately licensed Tamil TrueType font and include the `.ttf` file in the assets folder. You may need to specify the specific font in the WebView as well; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701360/how-to-convert-the-tamil-unicode-to-tamil-text-in-android/5701481#5701481) for details.